# Removing white space surrounding pgfplot labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

does anyone knows how to remove the white space below the x-label and left of the y-label in pgfplots? (Not the space between ticks and labels - this is not a problem for me)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            xlabel={test label x},
            ylabel={test label y},
            every label/.style={fill=none,inner sep=-10pt}
            ]
\addplot+[mark=none]{x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you add an image with the result of your code and draw on that which white space you want to have removed? Because I don't know were the white space should be ... :(

Comment: hm, test if this: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={test label x},
    ylabel={test label y},
    ylabel style={at={(1.5em,0.5)}, inner sep=0pt},
    xlabel style={at={(0.5,0.5ex)}, inner sep=0pt},
            ]
\addplot+[mark=none]{x^2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
` gives what you after.

Comment: Thanks Zarko, this is a nice approach! But if i understand this correct, i have to adjust the label postion everytime when i produce a plot with different width/height ? With compat=1.18 the label postion is inside the plot - so it has to be adjusted. But nevertheless a first solution to my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={test label x},
ylabel={test label y},
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks,
%label style={inner sep=0pt}, %even less space
%tick label style={inner sep=0pt}, %even less space
]
\addplot[blue]{x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with less space around labels]

Comment: Yes thanks - without the "border=1cm" and with "the label style={inner sep=0pt}" it is exactly what I had in mind! Problem solved.